# Loading tabs with data in ASP.NET Core Razor pages (without Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm working with ASP.NET Core Razor pages and an Oracle database. The team has decided to go without Entity Framework and now I am at the point of loading data from the database using ODP.net (Oracle's version of ADO.NET).

I know with Entity Framework, I could take advantage of asynchronous programming but since I am not, loading the page is slow (since I query all the tabs at once). I am using Bootstraps nav tabs.

Everything works fine but now the data set is getting bigger because there are over ten tabs that load on page load. Is there a way to only load each tab on click? Are there other ways to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question entirely. But how I read this question is you have to load your page whenever a tab changes and don't want to load the entire page at once at the beginning. This has nothing to do with which ORM you use at the backend as I see it. What need to make a asynchronous javascript call to the server when user clicks on the tab and load a partial page under that tab.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

1. show.bs.tab (on the to-be-shown tab)
2. shown.bs.tab (on the newly-active just-shown tab, the same one as for the show.bs.tab event)

I suggest you use the first event and in that event make an ajax call to a partial page.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/partial-update

```
@page
@model RazorPagesTests.Pages.AjaxPartialModel
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<p><button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">Load</button></p>
<div id="grid"></div>
@section scripts{
    <script>
        document.getElementById('load').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/ajaxpartial?handler=CarPartial')
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    document.getElementById('grid').innerHTML = result;
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Hope it helps. If not then I'm here to help you. Please give me more information what you want to do.